# string or enum, performance in c#

Tags: c#

I have a user control which has a collection of items of type MyItem which looks like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    // some other members
    public object Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I have many types of items in the collection and when they are clicked I need to know which one is clicked to take action accordingly.

Example:

If I have 5 items e.g. `Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4 and Type5` so to check on the item click event which one was clicked I made an enum like this:

```
private enum MyTypeEnum
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3,
    Type4,
    Type5
}
```

and put that into the `Tag` property of `MyItem` like this:

```
MyItem m1 = new MyItem { Tag = MyTypeEnum.Type1 };
MyItem m2 = new MyItem { Tag = MyTypeEnum.Type2 };
MyItem m3 = new MyItem { Tag = MyTypeEnum.Type3 };
MyItem m4 = new MyItem { Tag = MyTypeEnum.Type4 };
MyItem m5 = new MyItem { Tag = MyTypeEnum.Type5 };
```

and on the item click event i retrieve it like this:

```
MyTypeEnum tag = (MyTypeEnum )item.Tag;
```

So, I know when I put MyTypeEnum in the Tag I am doing `boxing` and when I retrieve it in the click event I am doing `unboxing`.

I can avoid it by putting `string type` into the tag.

My question is which is better `enum` or `string` performance wise or architecture ( better way of doing things ) wise?

Comment: Why not `Tag` of type `MyTypeEnum` directly?

Comment: Depends what operations you are doing other than the boxing. Comparisons on strings will be slower than comparisons on enums. Remember not to _micro optimize_ or _pre optimize_. This is a non-issue in most applications.

Comment: @RohitVats If Tag is MyTypeEnum then if I have 100 user controls then I will have to make so many enum items.

Comment: You would have to read and write these properties many, many times before you will start noticing it. Type safety will be a bigger issue because casting to and from type will cost you time during development due to hunting bugs.

Comment: @Kush enums are just Int32. Strings are 16 bits per character.

Comment: A 100 items is nothing, you have spend more time on writing this question than you will gain.

Comment: @Kush - So how `object` is solving that. In that case too you will create 100 enum types. Isn't it?

Comment: This smells like "premature optimization"... the difference between the two situations will be hardly noticed even if performed a lot of times, then I really doubt you can notice the difference when you click on a button a bunch of times...

Comment: *My question is which is better `enum` or `string` performance wise or architecture ( better way of doing things ) wise?* `string` architecture is much better than `enum` architecture but really you want to use an `StringBuilder singleton pattern` architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise it really doesn't make any noticeable difference. If you use enums, then you allocate one (boxed) object on the heap for each value. If you use strings, you allocate one (slightly larger) object on the heap for each value.

Boxing/unboxing becomes a performance issue only if you do it many 1,000's or 1,000,000's of times.

What is best from an architecture perspective depends on what you plan on doing with the tag.

If all you want to do is determine the source of the click event, then enums could be beneficial, since you can use them in switch statements, for example. Then again, you can use strings as keys in a dictionary. I would go with whatever makes your code cleaner and easier to maintain.